# Where are the Android icon drawables within the SDK?

Tags: android, android-drawable

In my design of UI of Android applications, I need some drawables for icons.

Where are the existing drawables located within the Android SDK?

Answer (score 47):

In `android.R.drawable`, read more here : http://docs.since2006.com/android/2.1-drawables.php

---

Simple resource usage :

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
```

Simple Java usage :

```
myMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems not many though. I do not find what I want. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I think the link may now be broken

Comment: There's a list of names here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable - no images shown though

Answer (score 11):

i found mine here:

~/android-sdks/platforms/android-23/data/res/drawable...

Answer (score 5):

You can find android drawables icons from the example path below...

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25\data\res\drawable-xhdpi

Answer (score 5):

A huge collection of useful icons is easily accessible like this:

1. Right click on Drawable folder
2. Click on New
3. Click on Vector Asset
4. In the dialog, click the button in the third row with a random icon, next to the label "Clip Art:".
   You can pick from the huge collection, then customize size and color.

Answer (score 4):

Add icon: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

set icon: `setIcon(R.drawable.ic_incon_name)`

Answer (score 3):

https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

This Material design resource from Google might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on Drawable folder
2. click on new
3. click on image asset

Then you can select an icon type